# Traceback, 'module' has no attribute I don't know why

Tags: python, traceback

test.py

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.Telebot(config.TOKEN)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

config.py

```
TOKEN='1030045171:AAFPptKPt0a7xcoev9ryIMb6jXEIck5QfOs'
```

gives error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\telegram\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    bot = telebot.Telebot(config.TOKEN)
AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'Telebot'
```

Comment: Is that token your real token? Might wanna change it now that you posted it here. Do you happen to have a file called `telebot.py` in the same folder?

Comment: it is just a test, so i don't care bout it

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled TeleBot

```
import telebot 
bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")
```

From the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/)